# Jackson reference object created from parent node

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have the following data model in json format:

```
{ 
  "foo":{
    "foo_property": 1,
    "foo_property2": 2,
    "bars":[
      {"bar_property": 3},
      {"bar_property": 9},
      ...
    ]
}
```

And my object model is as following:

```
public class Foo{
    private int foo_property;
    private int foo_property2;
}

public class Bar{
    private Foo foo;
    private int bar_property;

    public Bar(Foo foo){
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

When deserializing the json structure, how can I tell Jackson to create the `Bar`s objects using the created `Foo` object from the parent node?

Answer (score 1):

Next code works and add Foo reference in Bar field.
Main class:

```
 String jsonString = "{...}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Complex complex = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Complex.class);
```

Complex class aggregate Foo instance and add reference to Bar:

```
public class Complex {

    private Foo foo;

    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        for(Bar bar : foo.getBars()) {
            bar.setFoo(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

Also need change Foo class:

```
public class Foo {

    private int foo_property;
    private int foo_property2;
    private List<Bar> bars;

    public Foo() {;
    }

    public void setBars(List<Bar> bars) {
        this.bars = bars;
    }

    public List<Bar> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

    public void setFoo_property(int foo_property) {
        this.foo_property = foo_property;
    }

    public void setFoo_property2(int foo_property2) {
        this.foo_property2 = foo_property2;
    }
}
```

And Bar class:

```
public class Bar {

    private Foo foo;
    private int bar_property;

    public Bar() {
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void setBar_property(int bar_property) {
        this.bar_property = bar_property;
    }
}
```

NB! But better variant - use inner class. Then you easily get reference to Foo instance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to deserialize your JSON, make the classes similar to the JSON.

As per the JSON structure, `Foo` is the parent node, and `Bar` is a JSONArray inside it. Use the following classes, and your deserialization should work perfectly.

```
public class Foo{
    private int foo_property;
    private int foo_property2;
    private List<Bar> bars;
}

public class Bar{
    private int bar_property;

    public Bar(Foo foo){
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't match my object model. I need `Bar` to be able to reference `Foo`